# JWT login issue

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I'm using JWT with Passport for authentication in my app. I use MongoDB and Mongoose for database. I added a user with username = manager and password=manager with addManager function the password saved in db is not "manager" and is : "$2b$10$O7YAgTJKETOY.lanZoErWum2e6ZPpVi.RjMp0VHKfMT82z9uEmrlS" I don't know why! and I can't login with password :"manager". I don't know what is the problem .I used [this article](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314) for my code. if you understand what't wrong please tell me.

app.js :

```
//settings and Requirements
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('./api/config/database');
mongoose.connect(config.database);
let db = mongoose.connection;
require('./api/config/auth');
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('connected to mongodb...');
});
db.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
let User = require('./api/models/user');
let basics = require('./api/config/basics');
let port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({
   type: 'application/vnd/api+json'
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
basics.addManager(basics.manager);
router(app);

app.listen(port, function (err) {
    if(err)
    console.log(err);

    console.log("port is " + port);
});
```

auth.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../../api/models/user');
const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const JWTStrategy   = passportJWT.Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, 
function (username, password, cb) {
    //this one is typically a DB call. Assume that the returned user object is pre-formatted and ready for storing in JWT
    return User.findOne({username:username, password:password})
       .then(user => {
           if (!user) {
               return cb(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username or password.'});
           }
           return cb(null, user, {message: 'Logged In Successfully'});
      })
      .catch(err => cb(err));
}
));

passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey   : 'your_jwt_secret'
},
function (jwtPayload, cb) {

    //find the user in db if needed. This functionality may be omitted if you store everything you'll need in JWT payload.
    return User.findOneById(jwtPayload.id)
        .then(user => {
            return cb(null, user);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return cb(err);
        });
}
));
```

authenticate.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
        console.log(user);
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: info ? info.message : 'Login failed',
                user   : user
            });
        }
       req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
           if (err) {
               res.send(err);
           }
           // generate a signed son web token with the contents of user object and return it in the response
           const token = jwt.sign(user, 'your_jwt_secret');
           return res.json({user, token});
        });
    })(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

addManager:
`

```
addManager : function(manager){
        let newUser = new User({
            username : manager.username,
            password : manager.password,
            isManager : true
        });
        newUser.save(function(err , user){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            console.log('manager added successfuly');
        });
    }
```

`

Comment: Bro post the minimal code needed to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: A lot of code and not much text. The only question seems to be, "why is the password saved like this and not as a clear text?" right? And as a result of this problem, you can't verify the password and therefore no token os created, right?

Comment: Hi. yes exactly that's my problem. I'm sorry I thought it's necessary to copy all the codes in here.

Comment: Your password is hashed so the password will not be 'manager'